# MahApps.Metro TabControl Laggy with filled GridView

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik, lag, mahapps.metro

I have a TabControl with 4 TabItems. Inside each TabItem I have a GridView and a Toolbar.
I use MahApps.Metro (for Window and TabControl) and telerik RadControls (for GridView and Toolbar).
I use MahApps.Metro TabControl with AnimatedSingleRowTabControl, so each time I switch the tab there is a tab changing animation.

When the GridView is empty, the animation is smooth, but when the GridView filled with data, it's lag.
Each time I switch tab, It's always lag about 1-2 second(s). 
My tables only has max 73 rows. So, I don't think it is too much to load.

I don't know if this is because of I don't use the correct way to bind the GridView with Table or another reason.

I want to smooth the animation, so my solution either:

- Let the GridView empty when switched tab and fill it after the slide animation.
- Somehow make the animation smooth (change the binding way).

But, I don't know how to accomplish the above option :P
Anyone can help me?
Another solution is welcome.

This is my code:

```
    <TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
       <TabItem Name="Tab_Collection" 
                Header="Collection" 
                Style="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}">
           <StackPanel Margin="20,10">
               <telerik:RadToolBar telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Metro" 
                                   Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                   Width="338"
                                   GripVisibility="Collapsed"
                                   OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button Name="Btn_CollectionAdd"
                            Width="80"
                            Height="25"
                            Content="Add"/>
                    <Button Name="Btn_CollectionEdit"
                            Width="80" 
                            Height="25"
                            Content="Edit"/>
                    <Button Name="Btn_CollectionDelete"
                            Width="80" 
                            Height="25"
                            Content="Delete"/>

                    <telerik:RadToolBarSeparator/>

                    <Button Name="Btn_CollectionSearch"
                            Width="80" 
                            Height="25"
                            Content="Search"
                            Click="Btn_Search_Click"/>
                </telerik:RadToolBar>

             <telerik:RadGridView Name="Dgv_Collection" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Metro"
                                  Margin="0,0,0,10"
                                  Height="505"
                                  BorderBrush="#25A0DA"
                                  BorderThickness="1"
                                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  CanUserInsertRows="False"
                                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                  CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                  ShowGroupPanel="False"
                                  RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                                  EditTriggers="None">
                    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="30" 
                                                    Header="#" 
                                                    IsFilterable="False" 
                                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding id}"/>

                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="*" 
                                                    Header="Title" 
                                                    IsFilterable="False" 
                                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding title}"/>
                    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                </telerik:RadGridView>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>

    //I do the same for the rest 3 TabItems

    </TabControl>
```

I bind the GridView this way:

```
    private void loadCollection()
    {
       String conn = connection_string;
       String sql = null;

       try
       {
          sql = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Information";
          SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, conn);
          SqlCeCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

          DataTable table = new DataTable();
          dataAdapter.Fill(table);
          Dgv_Collection.ItemsSource = table;
       }
       catch (SqlCeException ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }

    }

    //load the rest 3 table the same way

    public MainPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       loadCollection();

       //call the rest
    }
```

NOTE: I'm still very new to WPF :)

EDIT:
I found out it's only lag on first access to the TabItem. If I click a TabItem then switched to another Tab it's lag. But, when I switch back to the previous Tab, it's animated smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put Gridview inside a Tabcontrol or you have to use "persistant" TabControl